# how to print fewer pages in CSS

Tags: html, css

My application has some sections, when it comes to print the whole document, it just prints each section on a seperate page rather than fit in the previous section, The reports looks excessively long, especially when there is no content to fill them. is there a way to group the headings so that there are less pages?

Comment: Are you asking how to **combine** CSS to use on multiple pages? In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it is clear, and shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Do you have `page-break-*` style for your sections? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: @OscarSiauw yes I did use page-break

Comment: So that's the one causing the section to print in new page

Comment: @OscarSiauw how do I fix it, I'm just a newbie for CSS, thank you

Comment: @grooveline do you need the page-breaks on your page? If not then remove them. If you need them, create a media print and remove the page-breaks for media print